# Can I ask questions about electronics here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I joined this community because I wanted to ask questions about electronics here, but looking at the questions here, I don't think so, but because it was written 'hardware', I am not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately questions about electronics arw off topic at  Superuser.com

Answer (score 7):

Questions about general electronics would be off topic here. You may be better off asking at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) if you are a hobbyist or engineer looking to implement electronic circuits.

The "hardware" you see in our help page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is very specific and qualified as "computer hardware". As in hard drives, motherboards, CPUs, and so on. The hardware questions we allow are only as they relate to the computing field.

That page goes on to say that general electronic devices are off topic on this site except insofar as the problem is in connecting to a computer.